# Is there any quick way to check whether scrapy login a website successfully?

Tags: scrapy

I am trying to use Scrapy to login Github.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

class AutoreplySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'AutoLogin'
    allowed_domains = ['github.com']
    start_urls = ['https://github.com/login']

    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={
                'login': 'ac',
                'password': 'pw'
            },
            callback=self.reply
        )

    def after_login(self, response):
        pass
```

When I logged in Github manually, I checked the box like "remember username and password". So if I don't log out, it should be automatically login when I visit Github again. I ran the script in terminal and it didn't come up with any error. However, when I visit Github, it requires me to log in. I'm not sure if my code works. I didn't touch Scrapy for a while. Is there any quick way to check if I am logged in successfully? Thank you!

Comment: After login print response.body and see if you are logged in or not !

Comment: Seems not. I added print(response.body) in the after_login function. Nothing comes up.

Comment: Your code is not correct :) you are just copy/paste from somewhere I think. Please try to do something yourself, and then we will help you

Comment: Kind of, but not actually. I don't know how to login with Scrapy. So I searched for an example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850755/using-scrapy-with-authenticated-logged-in-user-session  And I also asked for how to find login data before that. https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/88178260?noredirect=1

Comment: Simplest way: Replicate your code in the `scrapy shell`. There you can send the `FormRequest`, etc. and directly execute `view(response)` to open up the fetched site in a browser.

Comment: @rongon I follow your steps. The browser takes me to Github without login :(

Answer (score 0):

Code is incorrect. Often forms have hidden  fields. Server will check thus fields when you send credential data to server. I add loop to collect all input tag fields. When form part is correct it's possible to find account name in response page. If it exists you can go ahead.

```
class AutologinSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'AutoLogin'
    allowed_domains = ['DOMAIN_TO_LOGIN_COM']
    start_urls = ['URP_OF_FORM_PAGE']
    custom_settings = {'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': False}

    def parse(self, response):
        inputs = response.css('form input')

        formdata = {}
        for input in inputs:
            name = input.css('::attr(name)').extract_first()
            value = input.css('::attr(value)').extract_first()
            formdata[name] = value

        formdata['login'] = 'YOUR_LOGIN'
        formdata['password'] = 'YOUR_PASSWORD'

        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata=formdata,
            callback=self.after_login
        )

    def after_login(self, response):
        if not response.css('ul.dropdown-menu li strong::text').extract_first() == 'YOU_ACCOUNT_NAME':
            # Something wrong.
            pass
    # You have successfully logged in. Put you code here.
    pass
```

Comment: uhmmm...I already have my own account. I don't have to collect user's input. If I collect user's input, does it mean I have to log in manually every time before I run my script?

Comment: formdata dict have all you need. Jast set login and password to yours.